# How to code the following product?

Tags: symbolic, iterators

I am trying to examine the properties of the following product for a given tuple $\vec \lambda = (\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_n)$, then the product is as follows: 
$$
\dim \Gamma_\lambda = \prod_{i < j} {(l_i^2 - l_j^2) \over (m_i^2 - m_j^2)} = 2^{n-1} {\prod_{i < j} (l_i^2 - l_j^2) \over (2n - 2)!\cdot (2n - 4)! \cdots 2!}
$$
where $l_i = \lambda_i +n - i$ and $m_i = n- i$.

The function `dim_calc(n, lambda)` might take a tuple `lambda` and the length of the tuple, `n`, and then define the $l_i$ and $m_i$'s accordingly? I'm not really sure how to write this though...any hints for this symbolic computation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Solutions：***

Firstly,I give a number to `n`

```
n = 6;
lam = Array[\[Lambda], n];
l[i_] := lam[[i]] + n - i
m[i_] := n - i
num = Times @@ 
Flatten@Table[l[i]^2 - l[j]^2, {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, i + 1, n}];
den = Times @@ 
Flatten@Table[m[i]^2 - m[j]^2, {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, i + 1, n}];
dimLamta = num/den
```

[image: output]

***Summary:***

We can define a united fuction to caculate it!

```
dimLambataLeft[n0_Integer] := Module[{n = n0, i},
lam = Array[\[Lambda], n];
l[i_] := lam[[i]] + n - i;
m[i_] := n - i;
num = Times @@ 
      Flatten@Table[l[i]^2 - l[j]^2, {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, i + 1, n}];
den = Times @@ 
      Flatten@Table[m[i]^2 - m[j]^2, {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, i + 1, n}];
num/den]

dimLambataRight[n0_Integer] := 
Module[{n = n0, i}, lam = Array[\[Lambda], n];
l[i_] := lam[[i]] + n - i;
num = Times @@ 
      Flatten@Table[l[i]^2 - l[j]^2, {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, i + 1, n}];
cofficient = 2^(n - 1)/Product[(2 i)!, {i, 1 , n - 1}];
num *cofficient
]
```

***At last:***

We can check out wheter dimLambataLeft is equal to dimLambataLeft.

```
dimLambataLeft[n] == dimLambataRight[n]
```

> True

That's my solution!

Answer (score 2):

One way to set this up is to define:

```
n = 6;
lam = Array[λ, n];
m[n_, i_] := n - i;
el[n_, i_] := lam[[i]] + n - i;
```

Then for any j, you can calculate the product:

```
j = 4;
Product[(el[n, i]^2 - el[n, j]^2)/(m[n, i]^2 - m[n, j]^2), {i, 1, j - 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First product:

```
prod[k_] := Module[
  {n, num, den, ind, numerator, denominator},
  n = Length@k;
  num = (k - Range[n] + n)^2;
  den = n - Range[n];
  ind = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, i + 1, n}], 1];
  numerator = Times @@ (#1 - #2 & @@@ (num[[#]] & /@ ind));
  denominator = Times @@ (#1^2 - #2^2 & @@@ (den[[#]] & /@ ind));
  numerator/denominator
  ]
```

Second product (if you prefer):

```
prod2[k_] :=
 Module[{n, num, ind, numerator, denominator},
  n = Length@k;
  num = (k - Range[n] + n)^2;
  ind = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, i + 1, n}], 1];
  numerator = Times @@ (#1 - #2 & @@@ (num[[#]] & /@ ind));
  denominator = Times @@ (Factorial /@ Range[2, 2 n - 2, 2]);
  2^(n - 1) numerator/denominator]
```

You can test equlaity. Reassuringly

```
And @@ (prod[#] == prod2[#] & /@ RandomInteger[4, {100, 3}])
```

yields TRUE